# Minimize the code of conditional statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way so that I can minimize the following code-

```
    <div className="App">
      <Checkbox parameter={parameter1} setParameter={setParameter1}></Checkbox>

      { parameter1.country && parameter1.category ?
        <ShowData parameter1={parameter1}></ShowData>
        : ""
      }
      { parameter1.country && parameter1.category ?
        <Chart1></Chart1>
        : ""
      }
      { parameter1.country && parameter1.category ?
        <Chart2></Chart2>
        : ""
      }

    </div>
```

Here I have mentioned  `parameter1.country && parameter1.category` three times. I want to write just single time.

[image]

Comment: those three "conditions" are all the same - so why not just lump all the html into one block between `?` and `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div className="App">
  <Checkbox parameter={parameter1} setParameter={setParameter1}></Checkbox>
  { parameter1.country && parameter1.category &&
    <React.Fragment>
      <ShowData parameter1={parameter1}></ShowData>
      <Chart1></Chart1>
      <Chart2></Chart2>
    </React.Fragment>
  }
</div>
```

Based on your code sample, `parameter1.country` && `parameter1.category` is common for all conditions and rather use `?` ternary operator, I would like to suggest `&&` will reduce empty string on your code.

Use `<React.Fragment>` to combined all the similar components.

Comment: Instead of using `<React.Fragment>`, you can just use `<>` at the start and `</>` at the end. These give the game output, and `<>` is common practice to do.

Comment: Yeah any one of the preferrable, Both will work. Thank you @Samathingamajig.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div className="App">
      <Checkbox parameter={parameter1} setParameter={setParameter1}></Checkbox>
      { 
        parameter1.country && parameter1.category &&
        <>
        <ShowData parameter1={parameter1}></ShowData>
        <Chart1></Chart1>
        <Chart2></Chart2>
        </>
      }
    </div>
```

Comment: You can also try this.

Answer (score 0):

There is the same condition that you applied thrice in your code. And in all the three places you are showing nothing in case of the false condition.

I think you can do it by below code -

```
<div className="App">
  <Checkbox parameter={parameter1} setParameter={setParameter1}></Checkbox>
  { parameter1.country && parameter1.category ?
    <div>
     <ShowData parameter1={parameter1}></ShowData>
     <Chart1></Chart1>
     <Chart2></Chart2>
    </div>
    : ""
  }
</div>
```

Comment: Shows an Error-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2urE8.png

Comment: You need to put the component selectors in a div or react fragment. I have updated my answer, please check.